# Installing TA-Lib on python x64

Tags: python, ta-lib

I'm trying to install TA-Lib on Python, i'm using a x64 version so i can't install Ta-Lib using pip. I'm following [these](https://github.com/afnhsn/TA-Lib_x64) steps to run it but i have not clear the step 4: "Build the library nmake". I have opened the prompt but i don't really know how to build `nmake`, can anyone help me?

Comment: I faced the same problem and [posted an answer on this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49864010/2655263).

Answer (score 1):

in your env, run command: python --version, so you will know you python version. then download the appropriate wheel. if it is python 3.6, then download TA_Lib-0.4.15-cp**36**-cp**36**m-win_amd64.whl

Answer (score 0):

`nmake` is the `make` version of the Microsoft Compiler Collection. You probably don't have Visual Studio installed.

See here:

- https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

You have several precompiled packages, including `ta-lib`

Comment: I installed visual studio, i was running the VS prompt. After downloading the precompiled package, should i put it on my python 3.6 folder and run pip3 install ta-lib?

Comment: Visual Studio was therefore not on your path. You can put the package anywhere. `pip install packagename` will take care of installing it to the right folder

Comment: So, i downloaded the file and tried `pip install TA_Lib-0.4.15-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`, it didn't work, the error i get is `Requirement 'TA_Lib-0.4.15-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
TA_Lib-0.4.15-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: If you are on Python `3.6` and download the wheel for Python `3.7`, the installation is likely to fail

Comment: I did not see that, sorry, i'm so stupid lol. Anyway, i used the same command with the right version and it didn't work either

Comment: @mementum I am currently using python 3.7, and i have tried installing `pip install TA_Lib-0.4.15-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` still i am getting `ERROR: TA_Lib-0.4.17-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`.