# How to install TA-Lib in Google Colab?

Tags: python, ta-lib, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to install the TA-Lib package in Google Colab but without success.

I tried this [guide](https://github.com/afnhsn/TA-Lib_x64) and also
[Installing TA-Lib on python x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48251292/installing-ta-lib-on-python-x64).

I get this error:

```
import platform
print (platform.architecture())

import sys
print(sys.version)

!pip install C:/ta-lib/TA_Lib-0.4.17-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

#########
('64bit', '')
3.6.3 (default, Oct  3 2017, 21:45:48) 
[GCC 7.2.0]
 Requirement 'C:/ta-lib/TA_Lib-0.4.17-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a 
  filename, but the file does not exist
  TA_Lib-0.4.17-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this 
  platform.
```

Comment: Colab is run on Ubuntu Linux, not Windows.

Comment: Good to know, Thanks for the comment.  Do you know how to install the package on colab? or any guide?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Have you tried following instructions from here?

https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib

And change any `sudo apt-get` to just `!apt`. Any `cd` to `%cd`

Update: try this

```
!wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
!tar -xzvf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
%cd ta-lib
!./configure --prefix=/usr
!make
!make install
!pip install Ta-Lib
import talib
```

Update(may 2020): for binary install (no compile)

```
url = 'https://launchpad.net/~mario-mariomedina/+archive/ubuntu/talib/+files'
ext = '0.4.0-oneiric1_amd64.deb -qO'
!wget $url/libta-lib0_$ext libta.deb
!wget $url/ta-lib0-dev_$ext ta.deb
!dpkg -i libta.deb ta.deb
!pip install ta-lib
import talib
```

Update(may 2021): even faster

```py
url = 'https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/libta-lib/0.4.0/download/linux-64/libta-lib-0.4.0-h516909a_0.tar.bz2'
!curl -L $url | tar xj -C /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ lib --strip-components=1
url = 'https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ta-lib/0.4.19/download/linux-64/ta-lib-0.4.19-py37ha21ca33_2.tar.bz2'
!curl -L $url | tar xj -C /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ lib/python3.7/site-packages/talib --strip-components=3
import talib
```

Update (dec 2021): from @roborative, this is easiest to remember and take 3.8s (above is 1.2s)

```
!pip install talib-binary
```

Update (mar 2023): Colab is now Python 3.9, talib-binary is not updated yet, so revert to conda extraction

```py
url = 'https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/libta-lib/0.4.0/download/linux-64/libta-lib-0.4.0-h166bdaf_1.tar.bz2'
!curl -L $url | tar xj -C /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ lib --strip-components=1
url = 'https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ta-lib/0.4.19/download/linux-64/ta-lib-0.4.19-py39hd257fcd_4.tar.bz2'
!curl -L $url | tar xj -C /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ lib/python3.9/site-packages/talib --strip-components=3
import talib
```

Update (apr 2023): Colab is now Python 3.10

```py
url = 'https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/libta-lib/0.4.0/download/linux-64/libta-lib-0.4.0-h166bdaf_1.tar.bz2'
!curl -L $url | tar xj -C /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ lib --strip-components=1
url = 'https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ta-lib/0.4.19/download/linux-64/ta-lib-0.4.19-py310hde88566_4.tar.bz2'
!curl -L $url | tar xj -C /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ lib/python3.10/site-packages/talib --strip-components=3
import talib
```

Comment: Faster still is the approach suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69854772/2711105) of using pip to install `talib-binary`.

Comment: `!pip install talib-binary` doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Shayan I update the answer for Python 3.9 now

Comment: yesterday they updated to python 3.10 and it does not work anymore

Comment: @danialdehvan I updated it to 3.10

Answer (score 4):

The 2022 update provided in [korakot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49660479/2745495) works on Google Colab:

```
!pip install talib-binary
```

Then simply import the library:

```
import talib as tb
```

Answer (score 0):

#### !pip install TA-lib does not work so downloading `.tar.gz' will work

## First step: download

#### 1. using os package

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xGx21E4oafx4WQbOCSPtQsxkD-ruMdK-#scrollTo=Yy9KWlGas0Me

```
!wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz 
!tar xvzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
import os
os.chdir('ta-lib') # Can't use !cd in co-lab
!./configure --prefix=/usr
!make
!make install
os.chdir('../')
!pip install TA-Lib
```

#### 2. Using the `%%bash` command .

```
!wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
!tar -xvf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
%%bash
cd ta-lib
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
sudo apt upgrade
#!pip install TA-Lib
!pip install ta-lib
```

## Last step: `import talib`

**If you are using Ubuntu and Jupyter then this answer is helpful [Unable to install TA-Lib on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45406213/unable-to-install-ta-lib-on-ubuntu)**

Answer (score 0):

The way it worked for me from a container and running jupyter notebook is the following:
`import os,sys`
Clean everything if previosuly.
`!rm -rf ta-lib*`
Download the package
`!wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz`
Unpack the tar.
`!tar xvf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz`
`!pwd`
`!ls -l`
Move to the unpacked and run the files.
`!cd /home/$USER/work/ta-lib/ && ./configure --prefix=/usr`
`!cd /home/$USER/work/ta-lib/ && make`
`!cd /home/$USER/work/ta-lib/ && sudo make install`
Install now the package
`!pip install --user Ta-Lib`
Import and tadaaa!
`import talib`

Comment: Hi user789313, I did the same as you wrote. But as I run the 'import talib' I got error as follow:
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-4aaeb47f62d3> in <module>
      6 # !cd {nb_path}/ta-lib && sudo make install
      7 # !pip install --user Ta-Lib
----> 8 import talib

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'talib'