# How to install TA-lib in google colab? !make command fail

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, ta-lib

i have gone through the stpes mentioned in below  answer

[How to install TA-lib in google colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648391/how-to-install-ta-lib-in-google-colab)

```
!wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
!tar -xzvf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
%cd ta-lib
!./configure --prefix=/usr
!make
!make install
!pip install Ta-Lib
import talib
```

but in !make command i am getting following error 
(looks like space is My drive 
 at "ar x /content/drive/My Drive/app/ta-lib/src/ta_abstract/.libs/libta_abstract.a) ar: /content/drive/My: No such file or directory " )

on google drive creating issues, please let me know how to solve the issue

> gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../include -I../ta_common/ -g -O2 -MT
>   ta_TRIX.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ta_TRIX.Tpo -c ta_TRIX.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o
>   .libs/ta_TRIX.o  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../include
>   -I../ta_common/ -g -O2 -MT ta_TRIX.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ta_TRIX.Tpo -c ta_TRIX.c -o ta_TRIX.o >/dev/null 2>&1 mv -f .deps/ta_TRIX.Tpo
>   .deps/ta_TRIX.Plo /bin/bash ../../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile
>   gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../include  -I../ta_common/   -g -O2 -MT
>   ta_TSF.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ta_TSF.Tpo -c -o ta_TSF.lo ta_TSF.c  gcc
>   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../include -I../ta_common/ -g -O2 -MT ta_TSF.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ta_TSF.Tpo -c ta_TSF.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o
>   .libs/ta_TSF.o  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../include
>   -I../ta_common/ -g -O2 -MT ta_TSF.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ta_TSF.Tpo -c ta_TSF.c -o ta_TSF.o >/dev/null 2>&1 mv -f .deps/ta_TSF.Tpo
>   .deps/ta_TSF.Plo /bin/bash ../../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc
>   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../include  -I../ta_common/   -g -O2 -MT ta_TYPPRICE.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ta_TYPPRICE.Tpo -c -o ta_TYPPRICE.lo
>   ta_TYPPRICE.c  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../include -I../ta_common/
>   -g -O2 -MT ta_TYPPRICE.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ta_TYPPRICE.Tpo -c ta_TYPPRICE.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/ta_TYPPRICE.o  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
>   -I. -I../../include -I../ta_common/ -g -O2 -MT ta_TYPPRICE.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ta_TYPPRICE.Tpo -c ta_TYPPRICE.c -o ta_TYPPRICE.o >/dev/null 2>&1 mv -f .deps/ta_TYPPRICE.Tpo .deps/ta_TYPPRICE.Plo /bin/bash
>   ../../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.
>   -I../../include  -I../ta_common/   -g -O2 -MT ta_ULTOSC.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ta_ULTOSC.Tpo -c -o ta_ULTOSC.lo ta_ULTOSC.c  gcc
>   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../include -I../ta_common/ -g -O2 -MT ta_ULTOSC.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ta_ULTOSC.Tpo -c ta_ULTOSC.c  -fPIC
>   -DPIC -o .libs/ta_ULTOSC.o  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../include -I../ta_common/ -g -O2 -MT ta_ULTOSC.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ta_ULTOSC.Tpo -c ta_ULTOSC.c -o ta_ULTOSC.o >/dev/null 2>&1 mv
>   -f .deps/ta_ULTOSC.Tpo .deps/ta_ULTOSC.Plo /bin/bash ../../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../include  -I../ta_common/   -g -O2 -MT ta_VAR.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ta_VAR.Tpo -c -o ta_VAR.lo ta_VAR.c  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../include -I../ta_common/ -g -O2 -MT ta_VAR.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ta_VAR.Tpo -c ta_VAR.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/ta_VAR.o  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.
>   -I../../include -I../ta_common/ -g -O2 -MT ta_VAR.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ta_VAR.Tpo -c ta_VAR.c -o ta_VAR.o >/dev/null 2>&1 mv -f
>   .deps/ta_VAR.Tpo .deps/ta_VAR.Plo /bin/bash ../../libtool --tag=CC
>   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../include  -I../ta_common/   -g -O2 -MT ta_WCLPRICE.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ta_WCLPRICE.Tpo -c -o ta_WCLPRICE.lo ta_WCLPRICE.c  gcc
>   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../include -I../ta_common/ -g -O2 -MT ta_WCLPRICE.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ta_WCLPRICE.Tpo -c ta_WCLPRICE.c 
>   -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/ta_WCLPRICE.o  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../include -I../ta_common/ -g -O2 -MT ta_WCLPRICE.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ta_WCLPRICE.Tpo -c ta_WCLPRICE.c -o ta_WCLPRICE.o >/dev/null
>   2>&1 mv -f .deps/ta_WCLPRICE.Tpo .deps/ta_WCLPRICE.Plo /bin/bash
>   ../../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.
>   -I../../include  -I../ta_common/   -g -O2 -MT ta_WILLR.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ta_WILLR.Tpo -c -o ta_WILLR.lo ta_WILLR.c  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
>   -I. -I../../include -I../ta_common/ -g -O2 -MT ta_WILLR.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ta_WILLR.Tpo -c ta_WILLR.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/ta_WILLR.o  gcc
>   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../include -I../ta_common/ -g -O2 -MT ta_WILLR.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ta_WILLR.Tpo -c ta_WILLR.c -o ta_WILLR.o
>
> > /dev/null 2>&1 mv -f .deps/ta_WILLR.Tpo .deps/ta_WILLR.Plo /bin/bash ../../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.
> >     -I../../include  -I../ta_common/   -g -O2 -MT ta_WMA.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ta_WMA.Tpo -c -o ta_WMA.lo ta_WMA.c  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.
> >     -I../../include -I../ta_common/ -g -O2 -MT ta_WMA.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ta_WMA.Tpo -c ta_WMA.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/ta_WMA.o  gcc
> >     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../include -I../ta_common/ -g -O2 -MT ta_WMA.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ta_WMA.Tpo -c ta_WMA.c -o ta_WMA.o
> >     /dev/null 2>&1 mv -f .deps/ta_WMA.Tpo .deps/ta_WMA.Plo /bin/bash ../../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -version-info 0:0:0 
> >     -o libta_func.la  ta_utility.lo ta_ACOS.lo ta_AD.lo ta_ADD.lo ta_ADOSC.lo ta_ADX.lo ta_ADXR.lo ta_APO.lo ta_AROON.lo ta_AROONOSC.lo
> >     ta_ASIN.lo ta_ATAN.lo ta_ATR.lo ta_AVGPRICE.lo ta_BBANDS.lo ta_BETA.lo
> >     ta_BOP.lo ta_CCI.lo ta_CDL2CROWS.lo ta_CDL3BLACKCROWS.lo
> >     ta_CDL3INSIDE.lo ta_CDL3LINESTRIKE.lo ta_CDL3OUTSIDE.lo
> >     ta_CDL3STARSINSOUTH.lo ta_CDL3WHITESOLDIERS.lo ta_CDLABANDONEDBABY.lo
> >     ta_CDLADVANCEBLOCK.lo ta_CDLBELTHOLD.lo ta_CDLBREAKAWAY.lo
> >     ta_CDLCLOSINGMARUBOZU.lo ta_CDLCONCEALBABYSWALL.lo
> >     ta_CDLCOUNTERATTACK.lo ta_CDLDARKCLOUDCOVER.lo ta_CDLDOJI.lo
> >     ta_CDLDOJISTAR.lo ta_CDLDRAGONFLYDOJI.lo ta_CDLENGULFING.lo
> >     ta_CDLEVENINGDOJISTAR.lo ta_CDLEVENINGSTAR.lo
> >     ta_CDLGAPSIDESIDEWHITE.lo ta_CDLGRAVESTONEDOJI.lo ta_CDLHAMMER.lo
> >     ta_CDLHANGINGMAN.lo ta_CDLHARAMI.lo ta_CDLHARAMICROSS.lo
> >     ta_CDLHIGHWAVE.lo ta_CDLHIKKAKE.lo ta_CDLHIKKAKEMOD.lo
> >     ta_CDLHOMINGPIGEON.lo ta_CDLIDENTICAL3CROWS.lo ta_CDLINNECK.lo
> >     ta_CDLINVERTEDHAMMER.lo ta_CDLKICKING.lo ta_CDLKICKINGBYLENGTH.lo
> >     ta_CDLLADDERBOTTOM.lo ta_CDLLONGLEGGEDDOJI.lo ta_CDLLONGLINE.lo
> >     ta_CDLMARUBOZU.lo ta_CDLMATCHINGLOW.lo ta_CDLMATHOLD.lo
> >     ta_CDLMORNINGDOJISTAR.lo ta_CDLMORNINGSTAR.lo ta_CDLONNECK.lo
> >     ta_CDLPIERCING.lo ta_CDLRICKSHAWMAN.lo ta_CDLRISEFALL3METHODS.lo
> >     ta_CDLSEPARATINGLINES.lo ta_CDLSHOOTINGSTAR.lo ta_CDLSHORTLINE.lo
> >     ta_CDLSPINNINGTOP.lo ta_CDLSTALLEDPATTERN.lo ta_CDLSTICKSANDWICH.lo
> >     ta_CDLTAKURI.lo ta_CDLTASUKIGAP.lo ta_CDLTHRUSTING.lo ta_CDLTRISTAR.lo
> >     ta_CDLUNIQUE3RIVER.lo ta_CDLUPSIDEGAP2CROWS.lo
> >     ta_CDLXSIDEGAP3METHODS.lo ta_CEIL.lo ta_CMO.lo ta_CORREL.lo ta_COS.lo
> >     ta_COSH.lo ta_DEMA.lo ta_DIV.lo ta_DX.lo ta_EMA.lo ta_EXP.lo
> >     ta_FLOOR.lo ta_HT_DCPERIOD.lo ta_HT_DCPHASE.lo ta_HT_PHASOR.lo
> >     ta_HT_SINE.lo ta_HT_TRENDLINE.lo ta_HT_TRENDMODE.lo ta_KAMA.lo
> >     ta_LINEARREG.lo ta_LINEARREG_ANGLE.lo ta_LINEARREG_INTERCEPT.lo
> >     ta_LINEARREG_SLOPE.lo ta_LN.lo ta_LOG10.lo ta_MA.lo ta_MACD.lo
> >     ta_MACDEXT.lo ta_MACDFIX.lo ta_MAMA.lo ta_MAVP.lo ta_MAX.lo
> >     ta_MAXINDEX.lo ta_MEDPRICE.lo ta_MFI.lo ta_MIDPOINT.lo ta_MIDPRICE.lo
> >     ta_MIN.lo ta_MININDEX.lo ta_MINMAX.lo ta_MINMAXINDEX.lo ta_MINUS_DI.lo
> >     ta_MINUS_DM.lo ta_MOM.lo ta_MULT.lo ta_NATR.lo ta_OBV.lo ta_PLUS_DI.lo
> >     ta_PLUS_DM.lo ta_PPO.lo ta_ROC.lo ta_ROCP.lo ta_ROCR.lo ta_ROCR100.lo
> >     ta_RSI.lo ta_SAR.lo ta_SAREXT.lo ta_SIN.lo ta_SINH.lo ta_SMA.lo
> >     ta_SQRT.lo ta_STDDEV.lo ta_STOCH.lo ta_STOCHF.lo ta_STOCHRSI.lo
> >     ta_SUB.lo ta_SUM.lo ta_T3.lo ta_TAN.lo ta_TANH.lo ta_TEMA.lo
> >     ta_TRANGE.lo ta_TRIMA.lo ta_TRIX.lo ta_TSF.lo ta_TYPPRICE.lo
> >     ta_ULTOSC.lo ta_VAR.lo ta_WCLPRICE.lo ta_WILLR.lo ta_WMA.lo  -lpthread
> >     -ldl  libtool: link: warning: `-version-info/-version-number' is ignored for convenience libraries ar cru .libs/libta_func.a
> >     .libs/ta_utility.o .libs/ta_ACOS.o .libs/ta_AD.o .libs/ta_ADD.o
> >     .libs/ta_ADOSC.o .libs/ta_ADX.o .libs/ta_ADXR.o .libs/ta_APO.o
> >     .libs/ta_AROON.o .libs/ta_AROONOSC.o .libs/ta_ASIN.o .libs/ta_ATAN.o
> >     .libs/ta_ATR.o .libs/ta_AVGPRICE.o .libs/ta_BBANDS.o .libs/ta_BETA.o
> >     .libs/ta_BOP.o .libs/ta_CCI.o .libs/ta_CDL2CROWS.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDL3BLACKCROWS.o .libs/ta_CDL3INSIDE.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDL3LINESTRIKE.o .libs/ta_CDL3OUTSIDE.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDL3STARSINSOUTH.o .libs/ta_CDL3WHITESOLDIERS.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDLABANDONEDBABY.o .libs/ta_CDLADVANCEBLOCK.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDLBELTHOLD.o .libs/ta_CDLBREAKAWAY.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDLCLOSINGMARUBOZU.o .libs/ta_CDLCONCEALBABYSWALL.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDLCOUNTERATTACK.o .libs/ta_CDLDARKCLOUDCOVER.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDLDOJI.o .libs/ta_CDLDOJISTAR.o .libs/ta_CDLDRAGONFLYDOJI.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDLENGULFING.o .libs/ta_CDLEVENINGDOJISTAR.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDLEVENINGSTAR.o .libs/ta_CDLGAPSIDESIDEWHITE.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDLGRAVESTONEDOJI.o .libs/ta_CDLHAMMER.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDLHANGINGMAN.o .libs/ta_CDLHARAMI.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDLHARAMICROSS.o .libs/ta_CDLHIGHWAVE.o .libs/ta_CDLHIKKAKE.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDLHIKKAKEMOD.o .libs/ta_CDLHOMINGPIGEON.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDLIDENTICAL3CROWS.o .libs/ta_CDLINNECK.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDLINVERTEDHAMMER.o .libs/ta_CDLKICKING.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDLKICKINGBYLENGTH.o .libs/ta_CDLLADDERBOTTOM.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDLLONGLEGGEDDOJI.o .libs/ta_CDLLONGLINE.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDLMARUBOZU.o .libs/ta_CDLMATCHINGLOW.o .libs/ta_CDLMATHOLD.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDLMORNINGDOJISTAR.o .libs/ta_CDLMORNINGSTAR.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDLONNECK.o .libs/ta_CDLPIERCING.o .libs/ta_CDLRICKSHAWMAN.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDLRISEFALL3METHODS.o .libs/ta_CDLSEPARATINGLINES.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDLSHOOTINGSTAR.o .libs/ta_CDLSHORTLINE.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDLSPINNINGTOP.o .libs/ta_CDLSTALLEDPATTERN.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDLSTICKSANDWICH.o .libs/ta_CDLTAKURI.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDLTASUKIGAP.o .libs/ta_CDLTHRUSTING.o .libs/ta_CDLTRISTAR.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDLUNIQUE3RIVER.o .libs/ta_CDLUPSIDEGAP2CROWS.o
> >     .libs/ta_CDLXSIDEGAP3METHODS.o .libs/ta_CEIL.o .libs/ta_CMO.o
> >     .libs/ta_CORREL.o .libs/ta_COS.o .libs/ta_COSH.o .libs/ta_DEMA.o
> >     .libs/ta_DIV.o .libs/ta_DX.o .libs/ta_EMA.o .libs/ta_EXP.o
> >     .libs/ta_FLOOR.o .libs/ta_HT_DCPERIOD.o .libs/ta_HT_DCPHASE.o
> >     .libs/ta_HT_PHASOR.o .libs/ta_HT_SINE.o .libs/ta_HT_TRENDLINE.o
> >     .libs/ta_HT_TRENDMODE.o .libs/ta_KAMA.o .libs/ta_LINEARREG.o
> >     .libs/ta_LINEARREG_ANGLE.o .libs/ta_LINEARREG_INTERCEPT.o
> >     .libs/ta_LINEARREG_SLOPE.o .libs/ta_LN.o .libs/ta_LOG10.o
> >     .libs/ta_MA.o .libs/ta_MACD.o .libs/ta_MACDEXT.o .libs/ta_MACDFIX.o
> >     .libs/ta_MAMA.o .libs/ta_MAVP.o .libs/ta_MAX.o .libs/ta_MAXINDEX.o
> >     .libs/ta_MEDPRICE.o .libs/ta_MFI.o .libs/ta_MIDPOINT.o
> >     .libs/ta_MIDPRICE.o .libs/ta_MIN.o .libs/ta_MININDEX.o
> >     .libs/ta_MINMAX.o .libs/ta_MINMAXINDEX.o .libs/ta_MINUS_DI.o
> >     .libs/ta_MINUS_DM.o .libs/ta_MOM.o .libs/ta_MULT.o .libs/ta_NATR.o
> >     .libs/ta_OBV.o .libs/ta_PLUS_DI.o .libs/ta_PLUS_DM.o .libs/ta_PPO.o
> >     .libs/ta_ROC.o .libs/ta_ROCP.o .libs/ta_ROCR.o .libs/ta_ROCR100.o
> >     .libs/ta_RSI.o .libs/ta_SAR.o .libs/ta_SAREXT.o .libs/ta_SIN.o
> >     .libs/ta_SINH.o .libs/ta_SMA.o .libs/ta_SQRT.o .libs/ta_STDDEV.o
> >     .libs/ta_STOCH.o .libs/ta_STOCHF.o .libs/ta_STOCHRSI.o .libs/ta_SUB.o
> >     .libs/ta_SUM.o .libs/ta_T3.o .libs/ta_TAN.o .libs/ta_TANH.o
> >     .libs/ta_TEMA.o .libs/ta_TRANGE.o .libs/ta_TRIMA.o .libs/ta_TRIX.o
> >     .libs/ta_TSF.o .libs/ta_TYPPRICE.o .libs/ta_ULTOSC.o .libs/ta_VAR.o
> >     .libs/ta_WCLPRICE.o .libs/ta_WILLR.o .libs/ta_WMA.o ar:`u' modifier
> >     ignored since `D' is the default (see`U') ranlib .libs/libta_func.a
> >     creating libta_func.la (cd .libs && rm -f libta_func.la && cp -p
> >     ../libta_func.la libta_func.la) make[2]: Leaving directory
> >     '/content/drive/My Drive/app/ta-lib/src/ta_func' make[2]: Entering
> >     directory '/content/drive/My Drive/app/ta-lib/src' /bin/bash
> >     ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -version-info 0:0:0  -o
> >     libta_lib.la -rpath /usr/lib  ta_abstract/libta_abstract.la
> >     ta_func/libta_func.la ta_common/libta_common.la -lpthread -ldl  mkdir
> >     .libs gcc -shared  -Wl,--whole-archive
> >     ta_abstract/.libs/libta_abstract.a ta_func/.libs/libta_func.a
> >     ta_common/.libs/libta_common.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -lpthread -ldl 
> >     -Wl,-soname -Wl,libta_lib.so.0 -o .libs/libta_lib.so.0.0.0 (cd .libs && rm -f libta_lib.so.0 && cp -p libta_lib.so.0.0.0 libta_lib.so.0)
> >     (cd .libs && rm -f libta_lib.so && cp -p libta_lib.so.0.0.0
> >     libta_lib.so) rm -fr .libs/libta_lib.lax mkdir .libs/libta_lib.lax rm
> >     -fr .libs/libta_lib.lax/libta_abstract.a mkdir .libs/libta_lib.lax/libta_abstract.a (cd
> >     .libs/libta_lib.lax/libta_abstract.a && ar x /content/drive/My
> >     Drive/app/ta-lib/src/ta_abstract/.libs/libta_abstract.a) ar:
> >     /content/drive/My: No such file or directory Makefile:262: recipe for
> >     target 'libta_lib.la' failed make[2]: *** [libta_lib.la] Error 9
> >     make[2]: Leaving directory '/content/drive/My Drive/app/ta-lib/src'
> >     Makefile:283: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed make[1]: ***
> >     [all-recursive] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory '/content/drive/My
> >     Drive/app/ta-lib/src' Makefile:283: recipe for target 'all-recursive'
> >     failed make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install TA-lib in google colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648391/how-to-install-ta-lib-in-google-colab)

Answer (score 0):

If the space in "My Drive" is the problem. You can move to /content first.

```
%cd /content
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example:

```
!pip install feature_selector
!wget https://launchpad.net/~mario-mariomedina/+archive/ubuntu/talib/+files/libta-lib0_0.4.0-oneiric1_amd64.deb -qO libta.deb
!wget https://launchpad.net/~mario-mariomedina/+archive/ubuntu/talib/+files/ta-lib0-dev_0.4.0-oneiric1_amd64.deb -qO ta.deb
!dpkg -i libta.deb ta.deb
!pip install ta-lib
import talib
```

See: [How to install TA-lib in google colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49648391/55075)