# How to install TA-Lib package on Google Colab instance using pip?

Tags: google-colaboratory, ta-lib

```
pip install talib

Collecting talib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/80/3492aa3065d7d81a6c51db78920108f84fbe19c4e2740f6bbb83d42f77a4/talib-0.1.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: talib
  Building wheel for talib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for talib
  Running setup.py clean for talib
Failed to build talib
Installing collected packages: talib
    Running setup.py install for talib ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-kj3hzgy2/talib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-kj3hzgy2/talib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-utpwvbtw/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install TA-lib in google colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648391/how-to-install-ta-lib-in-google-colab)

Answer (score 5):

For me this is working:

```
!pip install talib-binary
```

Both on Colab and Kaggle.

Answer (score 4):

For me, copying the following 4 lines to Colab worked:

```
!wget https://launchpad.net/~mario-mariomedina/+archive/ubuntu/talib/+files/libta-lib0_0.4.0-oneiric1_amd64.deb -qO libta.deb
!wget https://launchpad.net/~mario-mariomedina/+archive/ubuntu/talib/+files/ta-lib0-dev_0.4.0-oneiric1_amd64.deb -qO ta.deb
!dpkg -i libta.deb ta.deb
!pip install ta-lib
```