# Talib install issue

Tags: python, ta-lib

Before I tell you about my issue, let me describe my environment:
Operating System: windows 10
Python Version: python 2.7(anaconda2 32bit) (My main enviroment is python3.6(anaconda3 64bit) which can install talib easily)
I have tried to search google but I can't find a clear answer.

Comment: Don't add screenshots. Include any code and error messages as text in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the user jtromans said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41155985/python-ta-lib-install-problems)

You should try installing [this verison](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib) if you are in python 2.7 and 32 bits look for this package `TA_Lib‑0.4.17‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I have fixed it by using your way!