# Module installation FAIL: pip install TA-Lib (ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1)

Tags: terminal, module, ta-lib

I am trying to install TA-Lib with the following command in the terminal.

```
pip install TA-Lib
```

Unfortunatley, I got the following error message:

```
Building wheel for TA-Lib (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1......
```

Many thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Installation process

install gcc first

```
   1. tar -xzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
   2. cd ta-lib/
   3. ./configure --prefix=/usr
   4. make
   5. sudo make install

   6. export TA_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib
   7. export TA_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include
   8. pip install ta-lib
```

if still getting error then install

```
    1. sudo apt install python3-dev
```

and then run

```
    1. pip install ta-lib
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow TA-Lib author "mrjbq7"'s full instructions here: https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib

You'll first download the built file from author, download and install VS community for the x64 command prompt tool, rebuild library, then finally install TA-Lib.

1. Download ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip from http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip and unzip to C:\ta-lib

TA-Lib is a 32 bit release and you might be running on a 64-bit python. So follow the instructions to build TA-Lib on 64-bit and rebuild the library.

2. Download and Install Visual Studio Community 20XX
   Remember to Select [Visual C++] Feature
3. From Windows Start Menu, Start [VS20XX x64 Native Tools Command Prompt]
4. Go to directory: C:\ta-lib\c\make\cdr\win32\msvc
5. Build the Library in command prompt with this command: nmake

Now try installing again: pip install TA-Lib

- you may also find other posts of similar problems here: [Python TA-Lib install problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41155985/python-ta-lib-install-problems/49807404#49807404)