# how to install Ta-lib with python 3.11 in Windows?

Tags: python, ta-lib, python-3.11

TA-Lib windows distribution from here [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib), but only support to 3.10.
How to install Ta-lib with python 3.11 in Windows?

[Instructions from the README for installing on Windows](https://github.com/ta-lib/ta-lib-python#windows):

> Download [ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip) and unzip to `C:\ta-lib`.
>
> This is a 32-bit binary release. If you want to use 64-bit Python, you
> will need to build a 64-bit version of the library. Some unofficial
> (and unsupported) instructions for building on 64-bit Windows 10, here
> for reference:
>
> 1. Download and Unzip `ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip`
> 2. Move the Unzipped Folder `ta-lib` to `C:\`
> 3. Download and Install Visual Studio Community (2015 or
>    later)
>
>    - Remember to Select `[Visual C++]` Feature
> 4. Build TA-Lib Library
>
>    - From Windows Start Menu, Start `[VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt]`
>    - Move `to C:\ta-lib\c\make\cdr\win32\msvc`
>    - Build the Library `nmake`

But then:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for TA-Lib
Failed to build TA-Lib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for TA-Lib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Answer (score 4):

The only solution that worked for me is this:
https://github.com/afnhsn/TA-Lib_x64

1. Download "ta-lib x64.zip" from github above.
   Extract zip file to `C:\`, so it looks like this `C:\ta-lib`
2. Download Visual C++ build tools 2022: https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_buildtools.exe
3. Install Visual C++ build tools:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/54136652/10997732
4. Install ta-lib: `pip install ta-lib`

Answer (score 4):

It should be noted that installing a wheel made for an older Python version (e.g. 3.10), but the correct architecture (e.g. `win64`) is *probably* going to work for you. This can be done using `pip install <path to .whl file>`. The main downside of this approach is that the prebuilt wheel you're using could be somewhat outdated.

Here's what I did to build it myself on a "clean" system:

1. Install the following **3** components from the VS2022 installer:
   [image]
2. Follow the instructions for building using `nmake` quoted in the OP. [[src]](https://github.com/TA-Lib/ta-lib-python/issues/127#issuecomment-280222942)
3. `pip install TA-Lib`

If you don't want to do any of that, I've uploaded my built wheel [here](https://github.com/TA-Lib/ta-lib-python/issues/127#issuecomment-1692950521).

Answer (score 3):

As of today, I found this link to get the latest .whl files for Windows OS [here](https://github.com/TA-Lib/ta-lib-python/issues/127#issuecomment-1692950521). Other methods failed, only the wheel file that exactly matched the Python version and Windows binary worked.
In my case, Python 3.11 on a Win x64.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the correct wheel file for TA-Lib and Python 3.11. I currently am trying to find the same file. 3.10 is the latest I have seen

> [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib)

Answer (score -1):

This works

```
python3 -m pip install TA-Lib
```