# how to install Ta-lib with python 3.10/3.11 in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, ta-lib

Following this post:
[how to install Ta-lib with python 3.11 in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75474154/how-to-install-ta-lib-with-python-3-11-in-windows)

I did all the steps:
-got zip file

- and nmake with VS

but, when I do 'pip install ta-lib' I got:

Collecting TA-Lib
Using cached TA-Lib-0.4.27.tar.gz (266 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Installing backend dependencies

so, it is going to use a installation file that does not works... and end up with

build\lib.win32-cpython-310\talib_ta_lib.cp310-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 164 unresolved externals
error: command 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120

So, we have 2 things here:
-going back to 'Using cached TA-Lib-0.4.27.tar.gz (266 kB)'
-and '... HostX86\x86\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120'

there is something I m missing?

br

I tried steps in :

- [how to install Ta-lib with python 3.11 in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75474154/how-to-install-ta-lib-with-python-3-11-in-windows)
- [Failed to build ta-lib ERROR: Could not build wheels for ta-lib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74651107/failed-to-build-ta-lib-error-could-not-build-wheels-for-ta-lib-which-is-requir)

Comment: See https://github.com/cgohlke/talib-build/releases

Answer (score 0):

method 1 follow the step from github:
https://github.com/TA-Lib/ta-lib-python

method 2 download the version for python 3.10 on windows, you need add the binary dir to win path variable
[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib)