# Failling to install ta-lib in Win11

Tags: python, pip, ta-lib

I'm struggling to install ta-lib on my win11 machine. What should've been just a pip install ta-lib and 20 sec later all done, transformed into an endless sequence of errors. I managed to progess with some of them, but now I am stuck with this one and no idea how to move forward:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe" /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\
ta-lib\c\lib /LIBPATH:C:\Users\cris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\cris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310 /LIBPATH:C:\Users\cris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310
\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPA
TH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.22621.0\\um\x64" ta_libc_cdr.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__ta_lib build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\talib/_ta_lib.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\talib\_ta_lib.cp310-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\talib\_ta_lib.cp310-win_amd64.lib
         Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\talib\_ta_lib.cp310-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\talib\_ta_lib.cp310-win_amd64.exp
      _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLBREAKAWAY_Lookback
      _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLEVENINGSTAR
.......................... (many similar rows so I deleted all to make error easier to read)
      _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_BBANDS
      _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_CDLRISEFALL3METHODS_Lookback
      _ta_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol TA_GetVersionString
      build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\talib\_ta_lib.cp310-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 339 unresolved externals
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for TA-Lib
Failed to build TA-Lib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for TA-Lib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Does anyone know how to escape this?

Comment: Did you look at this question before?  There's some pointers on things people have tried. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75474154/how-to-install-ta-lib-with-python-3-11-in-windows

Comment: Yes, and many others, because I made some progress initially.

Comment: https://devcodef1.com/news/1100127/install-ta-lib-for-python-3-12-on-win-11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/TA-Lib/), To use TA-Lib for python, you need to have the TA-Lib already installed. Download [ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip) and unzip to `C:\ta-lib`.

> This is a 32-bit binary release. If you want to use 64-bit Python, you will need to build a 64-bit version of the library. Some unofficial (and unsupported) instructions for building on 64-bit Windows 10, here for reference:

1. Download and Unzip `ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip`
2. Move the Unzipped Folder `ta-lib` to `C:\`
3. Download and Install Visual Studio Community (2015 or later)

- Remember to Select `[Visual C++]` Feature

4. Build TA-Lib Library

- From Windows Start Menu, Start `[VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt]`
- Move to `C:\ta-lib\c\make\cdr\win32\msvc`
- Build the Library `nmake`

You might also try the unofficial windows binaries for both 32-bit and 64-bit.

Comment: I've done these steps prior to posting the error. Also, that link does not seem to be valid anymore, I get "The page or document cannot be found".

Comment: Also, what maybe I'm missing here is what do I have to do after I run the nmake. Is there any way to check if the command was successfull? In my case, I went back to Pycharm and run "pip install ta-lib" and I get the error posted in this message. Maybe here I'm missing the bit... how to route the installation of ta-lib from my local folder on the c drive?

Comment: Yea, it's a shame they included such links in the docs. did you install TA-Lib? As you can see, you need Download ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip and unzip to C:\ta-lib in your windows machine before pip installing it

Comment: if none of this is working, and you're certain it's not an issue with your device, you can open an issue here https://github.com/TA-Lib/ta-lib-python/issues

Comment: The only thing I might be missing is what are the next correct steps after running nmake. First how to check if the result of nmake command is successful, and second, how to point the installation of ta-lib from my c drive ta-lib folder. I really have no idea when running a pip install "library" command from my Pycharm what happens behing the scene, so maybe here is the problem

Comment: Ok, I managed to fix the problem. Although looking backwards now, the solution seems ridiculously silly, there was a problem with the compiled result of nmake command. Without knowing how to check if the result was good, I deleted the whole ta-lib folder from C drive, un-zip it again from the source downloaded file, re-run nmake and the compiled result was much bigger this time, in terms of sequence of files. Went back to Pycharm, hit pip install ta-lib and it finally worked. So all the installation procedure described by user journpy should work just fine.

Comment: Glad you've resolved it